# Splitting up a a whole string and add spacing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a dumb question, but how to I add space gaps using split. I know it returns as an array, so I am not sure if its what I want to do. But this is what I am using right now:

```
         var GetME = $("#textinput").val().split(" ");
```

So for example, give if the user inputs TEXTTEST, I want the GetMe var to hold T E X T T E S T, is this possible?

Thanks Glenn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `split("")` without the space to break up the string into the array. If you want to add spaces in between each letter, use `join(" ")`

```
"abcdefghij".split("");            //["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
"abcdefghij".split("").join(" ");  // "a b c d e f g h i j"
```